# Select info from txt in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There is a text file that stores a log of processed files in the following format:

**Name: kn-25.txt Date: 01.02.2013 Time: 14:50**

The task  is to write a batch file which will make a selection from this file for a given month (mm) and year (yyyy) into the file result.txt.

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Введіть початковий файл:  
set /p in_file=%~nx1
if not exist %in_file% goto end

del D:\result.txt
set /a count=0
set /a con=0
set /a min=101
set /p month=Введіть місяць: 
if [%month%] == [] goto end 
set /p year=Введіть рік: 
if [%year%] == [] goto end 
goto start

:start
if count equ 0 (
set /a con=0 
) else (
set /a con=0-!count!
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%in_file%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-6" %%a in ("%%~i") do (
        for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%u in ("%%~d") do (
            if "%%v"=="%month%" if "%%w"=="%year%" (
                 set /a con=!con!+1 
                     if "%%u" leq "!min:~-2!" (
                         set /a min1=!min!-1
                         if "%%u" neq "!min1:~-2!" (
                            set /a count=!count!+1                    
                            echo !count!. %%i>>D:\result.txt
                    )
                )
            )       
        )   
    )
)

if %con% neq %count% (
set /a min=!min!+1
goto start
) else (
type D:\result.txt
echo 
@pause
endlocal
exit /B 
)

:end
echo Ви не ввели параметр!
echo   
@pause
endlocal
exit /B
```

I wrote this code, but got an error:

**Cannot find the file Name:.**

Any suggestions?

Note: *information in the generated file must be sorted by date*

**Example:**

*Initial file content:*

Name: kn-25.txt Date: 07.03.2013 Time: 14:50

Name: kn-26.txt Date: 02.03.2013 Time: 23:50

Name: MyFil.txt Date: 03.08.2012 Time: 12:00

Name: ca-21.txt Date: 28.03.2013 Time: 01:00

Name: ca-25.txt Date: 01.30.2012 Time: 10:05

*Input:* 03.2013

*Output:*

Name: kn-26.txt Date: 02.03.2013 Time: 23:50

Name: kn-25.txt Date: 07.03.2013 Time: 14:50

Name: ca-21.txt Date: 28.03.2013 Time: 01:00

Comment: 1) check the delims for your `for ... %%u` loop. 2) by quoting the values you force `if` to compare strings. So `if "08" gtr "21"` works perfectly. No need to remove any zeros. ("0" is greater than "SPACE")

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1-6" %%a in ("%%~i") do (
        for /f "delims=/ tokens=1-3" %%u in ("%%~d") do ( …` and [`%%u:0=` isn't a valid construct](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) and, using `GTR`,  compare _numbers_  rather than _"strings"_.

Comment: I've added ~ to ("%%~i") and "%%~d" and deleted :0 from  %%u:0. But it isn't working.

Comment: And I have a date format like 01.02.2013. So `for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3"` should be like this (?)

Comment: @JosefZ: `grt` etc. is *intended* to be used with numbers, but also works with strings: `if B gtr A echo yes` (by comparing their ASCII-Values). By quoting the numbers, they are no longer numbers, but strings and leading zeros do no longer indicate octal numbers.

Comment: @Stephan What else could it be that the program isn't working?

Comment: Still not sure, what you really want to accomplish, but to correct your code:  1) you want to process strings, not files with your `for... %%a` and `for ...%%u` loops, so you need to quote: `("%%~i!")` and `("%%~d")`. 2) you need `!min!` with two digits: initaite it with `set min=101` and use `if "%%u" GTR "!min:~-2!"` 3) you probably want to append, so `%%i>>D:\result.txt`

Comment: You've told us that your input lines are in this format, `Name: kn-25.txt Date: 01.02.2013 Time: 14:50`, and I'm sure you've seen file handles, `1>`, `2>` etc. Well imagine what could happen were you to try to `echo !count!. %%i>D:\result.txt` if the last character of `%%i`, an integer, was mistaken for a file handle. Perhaps it would be safer to use, `>>"D:\result.txt" echo !count!. %%i` or `(echo !count!. %%i)>>"D:\result.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: May be I am missing something I don't see the point on using those nested loops. They seem to be replaceable for a proper `findstr` command.

Comment: Llor1s, @SNR may have a point. Does their code work for you / if not, how does it differ from your expected output?

Comment: @Stephan I know:) However, using quotes improperly leads to unexpected results, cf e.g. `if 11 gtr 5 (echo gtr) else echo nogtr` vs. `if "11" gtr "5" (echo gtr) else echo nogtr`.

Comment: @Stephan Well we are not quite finished) See the updated question.

Comment: the updated code gives me this for the input 02.2012:                                                                               
_1. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00
2. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00
3. Ім'я: ca-20.txt    Дата: 01.01.2012 Час: 09:00_

Comment: But I need all the dates containing 02.2012 sorted by date.

Comment: Is the file name format always 5 characters plus `.txt`? Then `SNR`s answer can be adapted with a minor change.

Comment: @JosefZ: correct, but here the date is always two digits (leading zero), so `if` works as expected.

Comment: @Stephan yep, 5 and more characters and .txt

Comment: @Stephan Do I need to use sort?

Comment: That was my idea, yes. But the `and more` makes that impossible. `sort /+n` would need a fixed length.

Comment: @Stephan Ok, let's suggest the input file is `mybat.txt` and the output file is `result.txt`. What do I do?

Comment: @Llor1s, is there a particular reason why your latest edit, uses syntax used in your initial question, `28/03/2013`. If you remember your initial code and question body used the forward slash date separator, but when it was noted in the comments you modified it. It seems as if you're unsure of your requirements. It is probably fortunate for you that `findstr` uses by default the `.` character as a regular expression to mean any character. Please therefore note if it really was a `.` character you wanted to match, that to use it as a literal character you'd need to use `/C`, `/L` or `\.`

Comment: @Compo, sorry for misleading. The initial task has `.` in all dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a slightly different approach (slower than the other ones, but working as intended):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set in_file=t.txt
set month=03
set year=2013

(for /l %%a in (100,1,131) do (
  set "day=%%a"
  findstr "!day:~-2!.%month%.%year%" %in_file% 
))>result.txt
```

Comment: This does not include the time as part of the sort. Reading the complete file thirty-one (31) times leaves something to be desired.

Comment: @lit: the question states `must be sorted by date`. No time required. And yes, reading the file several times is slow, but due to the limited count (31) in this case I prefer it over building an error-prone array.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting we ignore the first 22 characters `sort` command.

```
@echo off
chcp 1251 >nul
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Введіть перший параметр: 
set /p in_file=%~f1
if not exist %in_file% goto end


set /p month=Введіть місяць:
if [%month%] == [] goto end
set /p year=Введіть рік:
if [%year%] == [] goto end 

findstr /C:"%month%.%year%" %in_file% | sort /+22 > D:\result.txt

type D:\result.txt 
pause
exit /B

:end
echo Ви не ввели параметр! 
pause
exit /B
```

We can use `findstr /O` if we want an offset on each line.

Comment: `if [%month%] == [2]` then your search string `/C:"%month%.%year%"` finds months `02` as well as `12`…

Comment: @JosefZ, SNR: the suggestion in my comment to the question (regarding `set min=101` etc.) solves this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows machine, it will have PowerShell on it. Here is one way to do it. This assumes that the date is in DD.MM.YYYY format.

Since it has already parsed out the date and time with a regex, it creates a [DateTime] to associate with the log file line. It then uses this [DateTime] to sort the file, but only outputs the log file line.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$LogFile
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [int]$Year
    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [int]$Month
)

Get-Content -Path $LogFile |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match 'Name: .* Date: ((\d*).(\d*).(\d*)) Time: ((\d*):(\d*))') {
            #$Matches
            $fday = [int]$Matches[2]
            $fmonth = [int]$Matches[3]
            $fyear = [int]$Matches[4]
            $fhour = [int]$Matches[6]
            $fminutes = [int]$Matches[7]
            if (($fmonth -eq $Month) -and ($fyear -eq $Year)) {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Line = $_
                    Timestamp = Get-Date -Year $fyear -Month $fmonth -Day $fday `
                        -Hour $fhour -Minute $fminutes -Second 0
                }
            }
        }
    } |
    Sort-Object -Property Timestamp |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Line }
```

Invoke it using the following command. If you do not provide the parameters, PowerShell will prompt for them. That is like using `SET /P` in a cmd.exe bat file script.

```
.\logparse.ps1 -LogFile '.\logparse.in.txt' -Year 2013 -Month 2
```

If you must run it from a cmd.exe shell, use:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\logparse.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a temporary file containing the lines from the input file filtered by the given date information (month and year), but with each line prefixed by year, month and day as well as the time value, which allows easy alphabetic sorting that is fine for your fixed-width date/time formats:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "IN_FILE=%~1"
set "OUT_FILE=D:\result.txt"
set "TMP_FILE=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"
set "MONTH=03"
set "YEAR=2013"

rem /* Filter lines for given month and year, then write them
rem    to temporary file, preceded by year, month, date and `:`: */
> "%TMP_FILE%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%IN_FILE%") do (
        for /F "tokens=3-5 delims=:" %%D in ("%%L") do (
            for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%A in ("%%D") do (
                if "%%B" == "%MONTH%" if "%%C" == "%YEAR%" (
                    echo(%%C%%B%%A%%E%%F:%%L
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
rem /* Sort content of temporary file, remove prefix
rem    up to the (first) `:` and write to result file: */
> "%OUT_FILE%" (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('sort "%TMP_FILE%"') do (
        echo(%%F
    )
)
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%TMP_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```